# Can I set maxConnection in WCF RIA?

Tags: silverlight, wcf

I've experience with WPF and WCF, with WCF I can set maxConnection to limit maximum connection per service. Now, I'm moving that application to Silverlight and WCF RIA but I can't find that property so it can do only 4 connection parallely.

Anyone know how can I configure WCF RIA to accept more connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using a service behavior like so:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
  <behavior name="MyBehavior">
     <serviceThrottling
          maxConcurrentCalls="4"   
          maxConcurrentSessions="4” />
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
  <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
</serviceBehaviors>
```

Setting the [`MaxConcurrentSessions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.servicethrottle.maxconcurrentsessions.aspx) value may be the solution.

Hope this helps,
indyfromoz

Comment: Those properties can help to limit number of concurrency but if I set them to 20, 50 or 100 it can do around 12 concurrent. Are there other thing I need to do? (database setting etc.)